# image upload to drive does not create thumbnailLink immediately

Tags: google-drive-api

I have just started using google drive javascript api.

What I noticed is, when I upload an image using request, the callback is successfully fired; but the object returned does not give me 'thumbnailLink' for the image I loaded.
Of course, I do get the 'id for the file and can and do fire another call (to files/get) with the 'id' to get another object that gives me thumbnailLink properly.

Am I missing something? or is this the proper way to get the thumbnail link in the client immediately after the upload?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. The thumbnail generation is asynchronous, so the immediate response does not know the thumbnail URL. Sorry, I know this is a pain, but the operation could potentially take a long time, which would badly impact file create calls.